# How to enter data with leading zero into the excel using c# excel application

Tags: c#, sql, excel

I want to enter data into the excel. Here i am having a problem while entering a data which is having some leading zero es.
For ex:

I want to enter **024**[zero two four] into the excel and this data i am having in my datatable.
But in the excel generating it is being shown as **24**.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a Apostrophe before will solve this problem.

This will direct excel to treat cell as a text rather than number.

```
'024
```

will output

```
 024
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the cell format to TEXT before you do that. Since you are after all trying to store the text "024".  In the same vein, if all your data is meant to be 3-digits, you can use a specific number format, such as "000".

```
cellReference.NumberFormat = "@";
cellReference.Value = "024";
```

or

```
cellReference.NumberFormat = "000";
cellReference.Value = "024";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a DataTable you need to Take another DataTable and then you need to iterate through entire cells in the datatable and prepend the cells text with space i.e with '&nbsp';.We cannot modify the rows in the same table because it will throw an exception saying "Collection was Modified".We have to take a new datatable.

Consider the following code.

```
    //To get the result with leading zero's in excel this code is written.
            DataTable dtUpdated=new DataTable();
            //This gives similar schema to the new datatable
            dtUpdated = dtReports.Clone();
                foreach (DataRow row in dtReports.Rows)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dtReports.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string oldVal = row[i].ToString();
                        string newVal = "&nbsp;"+oldVal;
                        row[i] = newVal;
                    }
                    dtUpdated.ImportRow(row); 
                }
```

We can bind this updated table to datagrid so that it can be useful for Excel Conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way for this.
Instead of doing anything in the SQL query or to the value we can give a Excel formula of whatever we want to achieve.

For ex.

here i want to have 024 in excel. What i did is i edited the query and change the value so that it now looks like a formula in excel. So that when it will be entered in excel it will be treated as excel formula

```
string strf = "=CONCATENATE(" + 024 + ")";
```

Comment: Going down that path, you could shorten it to `string strf = "=\"024\""`.  However, I recommend [Richard's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9462181/740923) instead.